# Lock firefox settings

Tags: firefox

I need to lock the settings "remember my browsing and download history", "remember search and from history" and "remember logins for sites" needs to be locked off. I also need accept cookies from sites to be from visited and keep until i close firefox to be locked. The setting clear history when firefox closes also needs to be locked on so the user cant change this.

I think i need to make a file like this but not sure on where to save it and what to type.

```
//
lockPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```